# ArcGIS-Pro 3 Select Layer By Date and Time

Tags: arcgis-pro, select, date

I have a dataset which has a `Time` column similar to the sample data below. I am using the `Select Layer by Date and Time` to filter `daytime` records and then export that selection as a separate layer.

When I run the tool, I get `0` selected records. How can I fix this?

Sample data:

```
1/27/2021 4:48:45 PM
12/30/2020 8:59:58 PM
12/24/2020 9:18:21 PM
1/22/2021 10:38:24 PM
12/18/2020 9:12:52 AM
1/28/2021 9:26:15 AM
```

Input parameters:

[image]

Column data type:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this sounds, ugh, but just because you have a field named 'Time' doesn't make it a timestamp field type. Can you update your question to show the Field Definition of the field named Time? (I just wanna visually double-check)

Comment: Am facing same issue here. Was there any solution to this.